# Show syntax error in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

How to show slim syntax error in rails 4. When i used rails 3 and slim all slim syntax error i see in browser when i migrate to rails 4 the slim syntax error shown only in console. In browser i only see http 500 error and message [We're sorry, but something went wrong](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rcubx91zu9itmas/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-01-09%2014.48.17.png). How to show syntax error in browser?

For example how to show this error instead http error 500:

```
Started GET "/tests" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-09 14:44:55 +0400
Processing by TestsController#index as HTML
  Rendered tests/index.html.slim within layouts/application (2.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Text line not indented deep enough.
The first text line defines the necessary text indentation.
Are you trying to nest a child tag in a tag containing text? Use | for the text block!
  /Users/sergey-chechaev/rails/project/test_rails_4/app/views/tests/index.html.slim, Line 2, Column 1
    p = week_field_tag :week
```

Comment: Are you running your app on production or development environment.

Comment: development environment

Comment: Please show your development.rb file.

Comment: `TestRails4::Application.configure do
 config.cache_classes = false
  config.eager_load = false
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.assets.debug = true
end`

Comment: please post your index file

Comment: `form
 h1 Listing tests
  p = week_field_tag :week
 p = date_field_tag :date
 p = datetime_field_tag :datetime
 p = datetime_local_field_tag :datelocal_time
 p = time_field_tag :time_tag
 p = month_field_tag :manth_tag
 p = color_field_tag :color
 p = highlight "one two", "two"
 button submit`

Comment: I just simulate error by add one space instead two space.

Comment: i've got the same problem. @SergeyChechaev did you find a solution to this?

Comment: i did not find i am use terminal.

Answer (score 4):

In development mode, `Slim` syntax errors are not shown in the browser as there is an issue which is currently under discussion. It seems like Rails 4 and Slim are not communicating properly when the exception is raised.

Follow the ongoing discussion [on Github Slim](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/472) issue page